# How to indentify BPMN process in our code, methods or classes?

Tags: documentation, uml, class-diagram, use-case, bpmn

Where I work we use BPMN diagram for modelling our business processes of our company. We use some of UML diagrams too, like Use Case Diagram and Class Diagram, but we need to link several business process of the BPMN diagram with some  of methods or classes in the UML diagram or in our Code.

Basically we need indentify the business processes with our respective code methods or classes.

You Know some tool, diagram or some way for help us?

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to kindly ask you if it would be possible for you to share with me one or two examples of real BPMN process diagram models with the related UML class diagram(s)? I am searching for real examples of models to learn more about the way the different modellers built them.

Answer (score 2):

It can be Logizian form Visual Paradigm. It has a free 30-days demo. http://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/lz.jsp?edition=me. This is a tool apart from the appropriate UML tool. (VP UMP). What is funny, the VP UML has all the same diagrams, and UML diagrams in addition. 
So, I'd try the VP UML.

As for Sparx, its Enterprise Architect (modelling tool including UML) supports BPMN openly. http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.2/domain_based_models/bpmn_1_4.html. Again, 30-days free demo. Here you have both UML and BPMN in one modeling tool.

Try what variant suits you more.

Notice, if you are interested not only in modelling, but in simulation of business processes, you need the very expensive enterprise versions of those SW. On the other side, some free/opensource/Apache [BPMN tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Business_Process_Modeling_Notation_tools) support simulation as well.